# nodejs mysql without callbacks

Tags: mysql, node.js, synchronous

Is there any way to execute mysql query synchronous? 
something like

```
getUser:function(user_id){
  return mysql_connection.query("select ... ");
},
```

to use it like  this

```
var user = getUser(id);
```

Answer (score 4):

In general the answer is no, unless you use a binding to libmysqlclient (or similar) that exposes such synchronous interfaces.

You want to avoid such synchronous interfaces because they will essentially keep you from doing *anything* else while the synchronous function is executing. For example, if you have a server running, that means you cannot service other clients. They all have to at least wait for your synchronous function to complete.

There are a plethora of ways to handle asynchronous tasks though, including "manual" callbacks (obviously), callback-based helper libraries like `async`, Promises, generators, async/await, etc. Some of these even create the illusion of a synchronous API without actually being synchronous.

Comment: If you using worker for the entire request it will not stop the execution, just this one until mysql returns the values. That is likely what all webservices applications made in other languages do (but with threads). I think the problem he and me is experiencing is all functions and methods needs to be async and await just because of that.

Comment: @OrlandoLeite All of the JavaScript runs from the same, main thread. When you perform a synchronous operation from JavaScript, no other JavaScript code can run during that time. So if you have an http server, that means you cannot service other http requests until that synchronous operation completes.